# same spacing between columns in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdUp7.png
and i tried to fix things with col-x-offset-x and it's obvious that it's not going to work. here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 "></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 pull-left"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 pull-left"></div>
</div>
```

how can i create something like that picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating it. It is just a matter of setting the number of columns adding up to 12 and then adding css properties to style them. I've added some nested divs to your code to show you the effect like in your picture.

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Y8CI0M0tXD)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3"><div class="bggreen"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><div class="bggreen"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><div class="bggreen"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><div class="bggreen"></div></div>
</div></div>
```

---

```
.container{    //create a different class name to avoid overwriting bootstrap
padding:20px;
background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.bggreen{
background-color:green; 
height:100px; 
width:100px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.row{     //create a different class name to avoid overwriting bootstrap
background-color:#ccc;
padding:20px;

}
```

---

EDIT

```
.parent{
padding:20px;
background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
.child{
background-color:#ccc;
padding:20px 0 20px 0;
margin:0;
}
.child2{
background-color:green; 
height:100px; 
width:100%;
}
.leftcell{
padding-left:0;
} 
.rightcell{
 padding-right:0;
}
```

---

```
<div class="container parent">
<div class="row child">
<div class="col-xs-3 leftcell"><div class="child2"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 leftcell"><div class="child2"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 leftcell"><div class="child2"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 leftcell rightcell"><div class="child2"></div></div>
</div></div>
```

Let me know if this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: it was helpful but i want first div exactly at the right side of the row, without any margin and the last div at the left side of the row. and same space between all divs.

Comment: Yeah, like that... thanks. is there any other way to do this? (without changing the padding of container and row class?)

Comment: If you're worried about using those particular class names then you can create unique names for the classes and just include them alongside the original class e.g. `<div class="container unique">`

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 12 columns in the Bootstrap system, you'd probably find it helpful to give each div a class of "class-md-3" and then use padding in each div to create space around your content within those three columns.

For example,

```
<div class="col-sm-3 add-padding">your content here </div>
```

Then, in your css file,

```
.add-padding {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

(I added the class "add-padding" to avoid changing all "col-sm-3" divs.)